# datePicker jquery plugin not properly load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the following plugin for date picking:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html

And I'm trying to use the code from the first demo but I get an error that jQuery is not defined (last line of the plugin, where the function is closed).

I haven't used jQuery before so I'm hoping this is a simple error.

I've tried to call it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        $('.date-pick').datePicker();
    }
</script>
```

^ Inside the head of the page.  There is also another jQuery code in the head, could this be causing a problem?

The plugin and other required JS are all present.

Adam

Comment: You sure that your jQuery script file is being loaded before your code above?  Because it sure sounds like it isn't OR you have a conflict.

Comment: Ah I see, I was loading the plugin before jQuery itself.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.date-pick').datePicker();
})
</script>
```

Comment: sorry that was a mistake in me copying the snippet, and I've tried you're suggestion and I still get the same error :(

Comment: It seems like the JQuery.js file isn't iclude or there are some conflicts. Are you using other JS frameworks?